# How to read a name and integer value in a comma separated string?

Tags: c, string, integer, string-formatting

I am trying to pass a number `N` and a set of string `S` as input. Here the string `S` contains a name `<abc>` followed by a comma `,` and then followed by a multiple digit integer `k`.

The program must display the name with the highest corresponding number.

Consider the following set of inputs:

```
4
Will,13
Bob,7
Mary,56
Gail,45
```

For which the output must be:

```
Mary
```

since the number corresponding to `Mary` is `56` which is the highest.

The problem I am facing is to get the name and number in two arrays namely `w[][]` & `a[][]`.

Here I have tried two-dimensional arrays, but I am not able to read the comma separated values.

Below is the logic I used for reference:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char W[200][1000]; // Two dimensional arrays to store names
    int a[200]; // To store the numbers
    int i, n, max, pos;

    scanf("%d", &n); // Number of Strings

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\n]s", W[i]); // To read the name
        getchar(); // To read the comma
        scanf("%d", &a[i]); // To read the number
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("W[%d] = %s a[%d] = %d\n", i, W[i], i, a[i]); // Displaying the values
    }

    // To find out the maximum value
    max = a[0];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= max) {
            max = a[i];
            pos = i;
        }
    }

    printf("\n%s", W[pos]); // Print the name corresponding to the name

    return 0;
}
```

So basically I want to extract the name before the comma (`,`) into the character array and the number after the comma into the number array.

How can I make this code optimal now in `C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general advice: prefer heap allocated values (and use `malloc` or `realloc` & `free`; read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)) to large variables like `char W[200][1000];`. I suggest to handle a `char**W;` thing.

> The program must display the name with the highest corresponding number.

Think a bit more. You don't need to store all the previously read numbers, and you should design your program to be able to handle a file of many millions (name, score) lines (without eating a lot of memory).

Then, `scanf("%[^\n]s",W[i]);`  is *not* doing what you want. Read *carefully* [documentation of `scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (and test its return value). Use `fgets` -and preferably [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) if you have it- to read a line, then parse it (perhaps with `sscanf`).

> So basically I want to extract the name before the comma into the character array and the number after the comma into the number array.

Consider using standard [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) techniques, perhaps on every line.

<sup>PS. I don't want to do your homework.</sup>

Comment: Yes I agree on the fact that the scanf cannot be used . Indeed I can try with fgets() . Thanks @Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: I have a solution using malloc and scanf() formatting.It would be great for your suggestion @Basile Starynkevitch

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char *str[100];
int i,a[100];
int num=100;//Maximum length of the name
int n,max,pos;
scanf("%d",&n);//Number of strings
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   str[i]=(char *)malloc((num+1)*sizeof(char));//Dynamic allocation
   scanf("%[^,],%d",str[i],&a[i]);
}
max = a[0];
pos = 0;
for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    if(a[i]>max) {max = a[i]; pos = i;}
}
printf("%s\n",str[pos]);//Prints the name corresponding to the greatest value
return 0;
}
```

I have used malloc to store the contents of the string dynamically.Also I have used the scanf() with formatting to get the string and the numbers in a seperate array.But if there is a better way on doing the same it would be really great.

Comment: You don't need `<malloc.h>` (which is non-standard) but `<stdlib.h>` (which is standard) to use `malloc` and friends.

Comment: You really should test the result of `scanf` (it is the count of scanned items). BTW the `%n` control to `scanf` might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information @Basile Starynkevitch.Will do the changes

Comment: 1) `scanf("%[^,],%d",str[i],&a[i]);` --> leads to Mary being printed as `"\nMary"`.  Should have followed the advice, "Use `fgets`".  2) What is the value of `pos`, if the first name has the highest number?